# RegEx to find Value of an Input with greater-than sign in attributes

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

This is a html snippet:

```
<input value="1" style="width: 90%;" type="text"></th><th style="cursor: default;" class=" filter">
<input value="2" class="tooltip" style="font-size: 0.8em; width: 90%;" placeholder="Datum" title="Datumsfilter 
Mögliche Operatoren: < | > | <= | >= | <> < | > | <= | >= | <> | .. 
Beispiele: 
2016 | 2016-03 | 2016-03-24 (nur Jahr[-Monat[-Tag]]) 
>2015-02 | <=2016-09-15 (ab/bis angegebenem Jahr[-Monat[-Tag]] inkl./exkl.)
2016-03..2016-04-15 (angegebener Bereich) 
<>2016-03 (ungleich)" type="text">
```

I must extract the value and it is possible that the type attribute is in any order.

```
/(?=<input.*?type="text"[^>]*?>).*?value="([^"]*)/
```

Works fine for

```
<input value="1" style="width: 90%;" type="text"></th><th style="cursor: default;" class=" filter">
```

But it breaks on ">" inside the title attribute from the second. How I can fix this?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with a regex.

Comment: There is no other option.

Comment: Why not? What language are you using?

Comment: Frank - bad idea, and it's annoying to ask this on this forum without at least SOME explanation of "WHY" it must use regex. That said... and let it sink in a bit... just a bit longer... it's hard to do what you ask with regex... let that sink in a bit... anything you produce in regex that does what you want is any where from fragile to criminally fragile... but it can be done

Answer (score -2):

Why not use

```
/\<input.{1,}?value="(.{1,}?)"/
```

it's a less complex: Just fetch the first "value"-tag (greedy quantifier) after each "input"-tag. Then get the value.

Note: I chose the greedy quantifier `{1,}?` instead of the `*` here to make sure, that the next occurrence of `value` will be selected and not any later occurrence.

But as mentioned: There might be better solutions than using regex here, for example if you are using php (? I don't know if you do ?). Depending on which language you are using you might have to change the regex-expression a little bit...

https://regex101.com/r/kB3wR2/1

Comment: Why did you replace `*` by `+` and then `+` by `{1,}`?

Comment: If someone were to be stupid, careless or mean enough to put `value="10"` into a different attribute (that is parsed before the desired attribute), this breaks. If a document being parsed uses single quotes (`'`) around the value of the value attribute, this breaks... ahh, using regex to parse HTML is fun, isn't it?

Comment: @fjellfly My question had nothing to do with greediness. The original regex was already non-greedy.

Comment: @CodeJockey: This is true. But for the given example this expression is doing its job. And since there's no more background information provided I think this is enough. To get the whole more flexible a different approach should be chosen, that's what I mentioned in the answer as well.
Melpomene: I know that the original regex was non-greedy - but my approach is. I explained why I used a greedy quantifier. Don't know what you want to know, pleas ask more precise.

Answer (score -2):

This is *Fragile*...

It can be *broken, circumvented and violated*...

It is *dangerous* to use it...

[Good luck for all who ignore these warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)...

There are problems galore to encounter and ways to pick nits out the ying yang, but if you have well formed HTML... ... ...

> you can try: `<input(?: (?:value=(['"])(?<value>(?:(?!\1).)*)\1|\w+=(['"])(?:(?!\3).)*\3))*>`

And you can [mess around with it here](https://regex101.com/r/nQ3rB3/1), if you dare.